# Correct way to use wp_editor in theme-options.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way that I can have wordpress let me use its wp_editor in the theme options panel. I am making my first WP theme and I am a little confused. I need to have some fields on my custom homepage be editable but not others and the ones that I do want editable need to be controlled via a html editor to preserve text formatting.

I am currently using a textare field like this...

```
//Paragraph1
$options[] = array( "name" => "paragraph1",
                "desc" => "Enter text for paragraph1 on the homepage",
                "id" => $shortname."_paragraph1",
                "std" => "",
                "type" => "textarea");
```

Could somebody please tell me what I would do to make a html editor appear under theme options instead of a textarea

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just include/output the wp_editor function in your switch case for that specific textarea type/id instead of your usual html  code.

For usage of the wp_editor see = http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor